# Pip is at /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip but python3 is version 3.8.1

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pip, homebrew

I'm a beginner. 
I'm trying to get beautifulsoup working. I went via Homebrew. 
I seem to have a situation where when I ask what version of pip3 I have the answer is
pip 19.3.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
When I ask what version of python3 I have the answer is
3.8.1
So presumably when I try to install beautifulsoup it's installing to an older version of python than the one that is used when I run a script in python3.
Is this clear enough? 
Basically, how do I consolidate this, or remove the 3.7, or what?

Comment: You might enter a world of pain here, but try this `python -m pip install` instead of `pip install`

Comment: Always use `path/to/python -m pip somecommand` instead of just `pip somecommand` -- https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Comment: (just a bit of advice)If you don't want to experience this type of painful event just use/create an environment for a project.